# Extract key-multipul values from .dict file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have .dict (dictionary file) of keys and multiple values for each key (mostly, because some have just one value) and I want to extract them in a specific format.

input file:

```
{"OMIM:614373": ["10280"], "OMIM:614370": ["6439", "1439", "6440", "21"], "OMIM:614371": ["30835"], "OMIM:614376": ["57728"]}
```

output file should be like that:

```
OMIM:614373 10280
OMIM:614370 6439
OMIM:614370 1439
OMIM:614370 6440
OMIM:614370 21
OMIM:614371 30835
OMIM:614376 57728
```

It's my first time to deal with such type of file, any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple iteration through dictionary and values of each key (if python 3.x `l.items()` if python2 use `l.iteritems()`)"

```
l = {"OMIM:614373": ["10280"], "OMIM:614370": ["6439", "1439", "6440", "21"], "OMIM:614371": ["30835"], "OMIM:614376": ["57728"]}
for k,v in l.items():
    for item in v:
        print(k, item)

OMIM:614373 10280
OMIM:614370 6439
OMIM:614370 1439
OMIM:614370 6440
OMIM:614370 21
OMIM:614371 30835
OMIM:614376 57728
```

Comment: @SaraWasl I'm glad that helped you, If you mind you can use tick button near answer to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {"OMIM:614373": ["10280"], "OMIM:614370": ["6439", "1439", "6440", "21"], "OMIM:614371": ["30835"], "OMIM:614376": ["57728"]}
for i,j in x.items():
    for items in x[i]:
        print (i,items)
```

this also can help you, same idea of arman's answer in general.

Comment: No probs ): Have fun !